# XCode IBAction and IBOutlets errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm having a bit trouble with my app and its really bothering me I was wondering if anyone could help me with IBOulets actions.

I only see action and nothing else, it won't let me change it.

[image: Error update]

any way to fix this issue. Thanks for any help

Comment: show some UI or code

Comment: Your question is not clear. Be specific with more info.

Comment: i updated the error

Comment: Would you like to change an object? Create IBOutlet in .h file

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: Ctrl+click on your UI object and drag to .h file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you drag your outlet between the @implementation UIViewControllerName and the @end (bottom section of the .m file) you create a IBAction (For example for button clicks)

If you drag your outlet between the @interface UIViewControllerName() and the @end before the @implementation, you create a IBOutlet. You can create it in the .h file and in the .m file. If there is no @interface in the .m file, you can create it. Add the following above the @implementation UIViewControllerName:

```
@interface UIViewControllerName ()

// HERE YOU CAN DRAG YOUR IBOutlets

@end 

// Here begins the viewcontrollers implementation
@implementation UIViewControllerName

- (void) viewDidLoad {
..... etc. etc..
```